# Number of threads with NSOperationQueueDefaultMaxConcurrentOperationCount

Tags: iphone, multithreading, macos, concurrency

I'm looking for any concrete info related to the number of background threads an NSOperationQueue with create given the NSOperationQueueDefaultMaxConcurrentOperationCount maximum concurrency setting.

I had assumed that some sort of load monitoring is employed to determine the most appropriate number of threads to spawn, plus this setting is recommended in the docs.  What I'm finding is that the queue spawns roughly 100 background threads and my app (running on iPad 3 with iOS 5.1.1) crashes with SIGABRT.  I've reduced this to a more acceptable number like 3 and everything is working fine.

Any comments or insight would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My experience matches yours (though not to 100 threads; do put in some instrumenting to make sure that you really have that many running simultaneously. I've never seen it go quite that high). Unless you manually manage the number of concurrent operations, `NSOperationQueue` will tend to generate too many concurrent operations. (I have yet to see anyone refute this with testable code rather than inferences from the documentation.) For anything that may generate a large number of potentially concurrent operations, I recommend `setMaxConcurrentOperations`. While not ideal, I often wind up using a function like this one to assist (this of course doesn't help you balance between queues, so is very sub-optimal):

```
unsigned int countOfCores() {
  unsigned int ncpu;
  size_t len = sizeof(ncpu);
  sysctlbyname("hw.ncpu", &ncpu, &len, NULL, 0);

  return ncpu;
}
```

I eagerly await anyone posting real code demonstrating `NSOperationQueue` automatically performing correct load balancing for CPU-bound operations. I've posted a [sample gist](https://gist.github.com/3343133) demonstrating what I'm talking about. Without calling `setMaxConcurrentOperations:`, it will spawn about 6 parallel processes on a 2-core iPad 3. In this very simplistic case with no contention or shared resources, this adds about a 10%-15% overhead. In more complicated code with contention (and particularly if operations might be cancelled), it can slow things down by an order of magnitude.

Comment: That's a reasonable solution for cpu-bound operations. I have a variety of cpu and network bound operations with quite a few dependencies though. It's tough to gauge what the "best" concurrency settings are here but I'm scared to set it too high after prior experiences. I could scale this based on device model – assume that iPad 3 can handle more than earlier versions and also account for network speed (WIFI vs 3G)... I was really hoping NSOperationQueue was going to do that.

Comment: I am experiencing the same, I am encrypting the files using RNCryptor and creating separate operation for each file. File count varies between 5k to 10k. Getting SIGABRT every time. Any suggestions to cop out with it.

Answer (score 1):

assuming your threads are busy working, 100 active threads in one process on a dual-core iPad is unreasonable. each thread consumes a good amount of time and memory. having that many busy threads is going to slow things down on a dual-core.

regardless of whether you're doing something silly (like sleeping them all or adding run loops or just giving them nothing to do), this would be a bug.

Comment: Not all threads were actively running when I tested this but each thread, regardless of state, incurs resource usage on the system.  I would have thought that the operation queues were designed to reuse threads - the process of spawning a thread alone can be taxing on the system.

Comment: @greg ok. good to hear it didn't have 100 active threads at once. and yes, i agree that these implementations should aim to reuse threads and balance loads well. if there are always queued operations, reuse should be high -- it's bad when the worker/thread creation takes more time and memory than the operation itself.

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation:

> The default maximum number of operations is determined dynamically by the NSOperationQueue object based on current system conditions.

The iPad 3 has a powerful processor and 1Gb of ram. Since NSOperationQueue calculates the amount of thread based on system conditions, it's very likely that it determined to be able to run a large number of NSOperation based on the power available on that device. The reason why it crashed might not have to do with the amount of threads running simultaneously, but on the code being executed inside those threads. Check the backtrace and see if there is some condition or resource being shared among these treads.

Comment: That's true.  It could be that that level of concurrency is causing a bug to rear its head.  With a reduced level of concurrency I'm not seeing any problems though.