# How to programmatically control and balance a number of threads iOS app is executing?

Tags: ios, objective-c, concurrency

How to control and balance the number of threads my app is executing, how to limit their number to avoid app's blocking because thread limit is reached?

Here on SO I saw the following possible answer: "Main concurrent queue (dispatch_get_global_queue) manages the number of threads automatically" which I don't like for the following reason:

Consider the following pattern (in my real app there are both more simple and more complex examples):

```
dispatch_queue_t defaultBackgroundQueue() {
    return dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);
}

dispatch_queue_t databaseQueue() {
    dispatch_queue_create("Database private queue", 0);
}

dispatch_async(defaultBackgroundQueue(), ^{
    [AFNetworkingAsynchronousRequestWithCompletionHandler:^(data){
        dispatch_async(databaseQueue(), ^{
            // data is about 100-200 elements to parse
            for (el in data) {

            }

            maybe more AFNetworking requests and/or processing in other queues or

            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                // At last! We can do something on UI.
            });
        });
    }];
});
```

This design very often leads to the situation when:

1. The app is locked because of threads limit is reached (something like > 64)
2. the slower and thus narrow queues can be overwhelmed with a large number of pending jobs.
3. the second one also can produce a cancellation problem - if we have 100 jobs already waiting for execution in a serial queue we can't cancel them at once.

The obvious and dumb solution would be to replace sensitive dispatch_async methods with dispatch_sync, but it is definitely the one I don't like.

What is recommended approach for this kind of situations?

I hope an answer more smart than just "Use NSOperationQueue - it can limit the number of concurrent operations" does exist (similar topic: [Number of threads with NSOperationQueueDefaultMaxConcurrentOperationCount](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11939773/number-of-threads-with-nsoperationqueuedefaultmaxconcurrentoperationcount?rq=1)).

UPDATE 1: The only decent pattern is see: is to replace all dispatch_async's of blocks to concurrent queues with running these blocks wrapped in NSOperations in NSOperationQueue-based concurrent queues with max operations limit set (in my case maybe also set a max operations limit on the NSOperationQueue-based queue that AFNetworking run all its operations in).

Comment: What do you mean "the app is locked"?  You will always have some threads executing, and as long as some threads are executing, your app will make progress.

Comment: What do you mean, "overwhelmed"?  If you submit jobs faster than the CPU can execute them, then the queues will be backlogged no matter how wide they are.

Comment: With the approach you are using (or NSOperation, for that matter), the creation and firing of explicit threads is out of scope. I don't necessarily agree that the problem is as you think it is - but, in answer to the question, the only way you can explicitly control the number of threads created is to create them manually, eg with NSThread.

Comment: Just adding my $0.05: The outer `dispatch_async(defaultBackgroundQueue(), ^{...}` is unnecessary, **AFNetworking** has its own queue where the HTTP requests are performed. The process of starting that request is so fast, there's no reason to wrap that in an async block.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are starting too many network requests. AFAIK it's not documented anywhere, but you can run up to 6 simultaneous network connections (which is a sensible number considering [RFC 2616 8.1.4](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec8.html#sec8.1.4), paragraph 6). After that you get locking, and GCD compensates creating more threads, which by the way, [have a stack space of 512KB each](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Multithreading/CreatingThreads/CreatingThreads.html) with pages allocated on demand. So yes, use NSOperation for this. I use it to queue network requests, increase the priority when the same object is requested again, pause and serialize to disk if the user leaves. I also monitor the speed of the network requests in bytes/time and change the number of concurrent operations.

Comment: You sir are a legend. I love this explanation very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

While I don't see from your example where exactly you're creating "too many" background threads, I'll just try to answer the question of how to control the exact number of threads per queue. Apple's [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/OperationQueues/OperationQueues.html) says:

> Concurrent queues (also known as a type of global dispatch queue) execute one or more tasks concurrently, but tasks are still started in the order in which they were added to the queue. The currently executing tasks run on distinct threads that are managed by the dispatch queue. The exact number of tasks executing at any given point is variable and depends on system conditions.

While you can now (since iOS5) create concurrent queues manually, there is no way to control how many jobs will be run concurrently by such a queue. The OS will balance the load automatically. If, for whatever reason, you don't want that, you could for example create a set of **n** serial queues manually and dispatch new jobs to one of your **n** queues at random:

```
NSArray *queues = @[dispatch_queue_create("com.myapp.queue1", 0),dispatch_queue_create("com.myapp.queue2", 0),dispatch_queue_create("com.myapp.queue3", 0)];
NSUInteger randQueue = arc4random() % [queues count];
dispatch_async([queues objectAtIndex:randQueue], ^{
    NSLog(@"Do something");
});
randQueue = arc4random() % [queues count];
dispatch_async([queues objectAtIndex:randQueue], ^{
    NSLog(@"Do something else");
});
```

I'm by no means endorsing this design - I think concurrent queues are pretty good at balancing system resources. But since you asked, I think this is a feasible approach.